# Can i use a for loop to use assembly language at each index, or do i have to loop inside the assembly language part?

Tags: c++, assembly, masm, inline-assembly

So i'm making an encryption program, where you enter a string input, and put it into a buffer array. Then for each character in the array, you use assembly language to encrypt it. You then take that encrypted string and put it into another buffer array. My only concern is that i only want to encrypt actual characters, and not empty indexes/0's. So for strings that are shorter than 127 characters, can I use a c++ for loop to check through the array for a `'\0'` character and only perform my assembly language encryption up until there? Or do i have to loop through the array in my assembly?

This is my code right now

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Encryption
{
private:
     static const int characterNumber = 128;
     char InputBuffer[characterNumber];
     char EncBuffer[characterNumber];
     char outputBuffer[characterNumber];

public:
     void InputData()
     {
          cout << "Enter a string to have encrypted: " << endl;
          cin.getline(InputBuffer, characterNumber);
     }

     void EncData()
     {

          char LocalInput[characterNumber];
          char LocalEnc[characterNumber];

          for (int i = 0; i < characterNumber; i++)
          {
               LocalInput[i] = InputBuffer[i];
          }

          for (int i = 0; i < characterNumber && LocalInput[i] != '\0'; i++) //Is this doable?
          {
               _asm
               {
                    mov esi, 0
                    mov bl, LocalBuffer[esi]
                    inc esi
                    ror bl, 4
                    xor bl, 10101100
                    mov LocalEnc[esi], al
               }
          }

               for (int i = 0; i < ? ? ? ; i++) //i < characterNumber && LocalInput[i] != '\0'???
               { 
                    EncBuffer[i] = LocalEnc[i];
               }

          }
};
```

Comment: You don't have to loop inside the inline asm; you can read any C vars you want into registers.  Of course with MSVC inline asm you can't do this *efficiently*: the compiler has to store C vars to memory for inline asm to access them.

Comment: BTW, `10101100` is a large decimal number.  Perhaps you meant to write a binary numeric literal like  `0b10101100`  (C++ syntax), or maybe `10101100b` if that works in MSVC inline asm.

Comment: @PeterCordes we were supposed to xor with hex AC

Comment: Then write 0xAC, not a large decimal number.

Comment: @PeterCordes gotcha